# If you have an array of fixed size, and you need to go through it !n number of times, how does using binary search change the time complexity?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, binary-search

We want to find all permutations of a string of length n. Then, you are to search an array of fixed constant size, say 3000 and check if the string is in the array.

```
String arr[3000];
```

Because we will have !n permutations, we need to do !n searches.
Also, what difference does it make when you check 2 different strings against an element in the array versus just checking 1 string?
What is the time complexity?
My thoughts is that it will take at worst, `log2(3000)` to go through the array once. Time complexity of that is `O(log2(3000))` which is `O(1)`.
Now, you need to go through this array !n times so time complexity is `O(!n)`.
So the binary search reducing the number of searches required should not be the focus when analyzing the time complexity of this algorithm.

My question is, binary search does reduce the number of searches and if you are gonna go through it `n!` times, shouldn't this be a significant difference?
Any insight to better my understanding is appreciated.

Comment: What is _!n_? What is _n_? You cannot remove data size this way from the complexity calculations. Otherwise, you could say: when I run the algorithm, _n_ is a constant, so _O(n!)_ is in fact _O(1)_. That would be nice :-). BTW, your question has nothing to do with C++ and StackOverflow as well. There are other StackExchange sites more suitable for (theoretical) computer science questions.

Comment: what do you mean by `go through`? Iterating over or finding a specific element? If you iterate over it, binary search is not even an option.

Comment: Here is the exact context of the problem. We have to find all permutations of a string with length of n characters. Resulting in !n of permutations. Then, you need to check the array of size 3000 to check whether it's in the array, or not in the array. Assume random distribution and is sorted.

Comment: Jaa-c, what I mean by go through is find an element, and it is sorted with random distribution.

Comment: You may want to incorporate this information into the question itself, because it is simply not understandable in its current form. Note, that factorial is `n!`, not `!n`.

Comment: @DanielLangr, n is not constant because we will be finding permutations of a string of length n, which will change. However, the array that we will check the permutation against is of constant size, fairly large, say 3000.

Comment: @geza, omg, I cant believe I kept thinking it was !n and not n!, but yes, they are obviously very different, but does it matter for the context of this problem?

Comment: Not that part was unclear, but the whole question. Now, it's better (we know what `n` is, etc.). Btw, maybe you want to solve this problem in a different way: check for each of the 3000 strings, whether they are a permutation of the string. This will be much faster, if the string is long. (i.e, instead of O(n!), this way is O(n))

Comment: @geza  I have already done that solution. I am asking solely out of my lack of understanding what exactly went wrong with my time complexity analysis

Comment: @GaryKim Hidden constants are hidden in a big-O notation, but they still matter a lot when you measure the running time. Therefore, algorithm with binary search will be very likely many times faster then that with linear search, though both alogirthms may have the same time complexity. Note that typically input data sizes are not taken as constants for complexity calculations.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thank you for your answer, that is exactly the reason why I was getting confused. My thinking and my confusion was, big-O tells me that doing binary search and not doing it results in equal time complexity, so why would I do it? The problem is, I completely overlooked the fact that there was hidden factors which may or may not exist. For example, I just threw out the factor of searching through the array on the basis that it can be done in linear time, but it is a significant factor and should have been considered.

Comment: Btw, you miss string comparison which depends of `n`.

Comment: And indeed, `std::is_permutation` or comparing sorted input would reduce the whole complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big O complexity analysis only deals with quantities that are subject to change, *by definition*. That you get vacuous answers when all your quantities are constant is expected.

The constant factors *are relevant* when comparing two algorithms of equal Big-O, so your change from 3000 -> log2(3000) is a factor of about 200.

Thus you use the binary search because you are doing more than Big-O analysis. You have also estimated the constant factors, and see an easy 200x speedup

But equally you can have multiple terms in your complexity. You might say:

- Let `n` be the input string length
- Let `m` be the size of `arr`
- Our algorithm is `O( n * n! * log(m) )` (`n` for the string equality, `n!` for the permutations, `log(m)` for the binary searching)

It also rather depends on a model of *cost*. Usually this maps back to some abstract machine, e.g. we assume that operations have a certain cost. E.g. You might compare sorting algorithms by *just* the count of comparisons, or by *just* the count of swaps, or by the counts of *both comparisons and swaps*.

Comment: I sort of am starting to understand where I went wrong.However, I have another question, how does the complexity change given that you need to check 2 different strings against an element in the array versus just checking 1 string?

Comment: But this brings me back to my original confusion... given that m, the size of arr is constant and will never change, doesnt that just mean O(n*n!*some constant) which is just O(n*n!)?

Comment: Yes. Big-O is a blunt instrument. It classifies things into broad categories

Comment: "The constant factors are relevant when comparing two algorithms of equal Big-O" That makes sense, but then, if you have 2 algorithms of equal Big-O, even one unnecessary if statement will make a difference(however small it may be). So how do you decide which constant factor is ok and which is not? evaluating an if statement is done in constant time just like searching for an element in an array of fixed size is.

Comment: Is the problem that, like you said, Big-O is a blunt instrument, one should use it carefully, and because of my lack of understanding, I ran into this situation?

Comment: Mainly, I want to know whether my analysis was wrong, in which case I need to learn the concepts. Or if the way I applied it is wrong.

Comment: `O( n * n! * log(m) )` is a meaningless statement without a definition of `n` and `m`. `O( n * n! * log(m) ) == O( n * n! )` has a different truth value for different definitions of `n` and `m`. Under the "hold `m` constant" model, it is a true statement. Under the "`m` may vary" model it is a false statement.

Comment: I get that the truth depends on the definition of n and m, and that if m is constant, it is true, if it may vary, it is false. However, in the context of my question, m is already known from the start to be fixed. So doesn't that result in O(n*n!*logm)== O(n*n!) in my context? Which again leads me to my original question, why use binary search? (This is exactly what's causing my confusion).

Comment: You use the binary search because you are doing *more* than Big-O analysis. You *also* estimate the constant factors, and see an easy 200x speedup

Comment: As an example, yesterday I changed an algorithm from `O(N)` to `O(log(N))` where `N` was in the range of ~100, because that particular calculation was suddenly occurring *millions* of times. Up till then the `O(N)` hadn't mattered. A factor of 100 can be the difference between "fast enough" and "user gets annoyed at slow computer", but only if it happens somewhere relevant

Comment: "You use the binary search because you are doing more than Big-O analysis. You also estimate the constant factors, and see an easy 200x speedup" that pretty much resolved my confusion. Just one last thing, if you dont mind, so in what context would doing Big-O analysis give you more insight about the nature of the algorithm? I can clearly see how foolish it was to do Big-O analysis in the first place when the answer was clear, should you do binary search or not? Yes, because its better than linear search.

Comment: Ahh, I see, similar to your scenario, if the array was of size 10, lets say. It wouldn't really matter, whereas for size 3000, it does make a difference.

Comment: You might compare "sort input then binary search" with "leave input in arbitrary order and linear search" by estimating how often the search occurs compared to the sort